# Raphael Hit Detection

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael

I am trying to determine when a newly created path is dragged over another path.  I have tried  a few things, but nothing works reliably.

onDragOver - I tried using the onDragOver event for the target path, but this seems to never get called.

getElementsByPoint() - This is very unreliable.  This returns my target about 1 in 5 times.

I have a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/acabler/Uk765/43/) that shows the problem.
(I realize that the offset is slightly off, but it still shows the problem.)

To see the issue, drag from the bottom line to the top.  Once over the top line, a console message should be printed, but this only happens sometimes.

I would like to know the following:
1)  Am I just doing it wrong?
2)  Is there a way to get this to work?
3)  Are there known bugs in Raphael preventing this from working?

Answer (score 0):

[Graphiti](http://draw2d.org/graphiti/jsdoc/#!/example), which is an abstraction of raphaelJS, did have a hitTest for line/polyline and 
curves.

Comment: Please see [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) (And please revise your other posts too.)

Comment: Agree with above.  This is a fine comment, but doesn't answer the question.